# Arithmetic Progression of a book

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Given that a book starts on page 1, and is numbered on each page

a) Show that the first eleven pages contain 13 digits

b) If total number of digits is 1260, how many pages are in the book?

So, If it starts on page 1, that means $U_1=1$ and $U_n=n$

But what Im trying to figure out is what the formula for

$U_{digits}$ would be.

I tried making a chart, to see the correlation between the set of pages and the set of digits, and noticed that, up to 9 it is $n+1$. After $10$ until $99$ it is $n+2$. After $100$ until $999$ it is $n+3$

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are $9$ single-digit positive integers, $99 - 9 = 90$ two-digit positive integers, and $999 - 99 = 900$ three-digit positive integers.  The nine pages numbered with a single digit have $9 \cdot 1 = 9$ digits on them.  The $90$ pages numbered with two digits have $90 \cdot 2 = 180$ digits on them.  Thus, at the end of the first $99$ pages, we have encountered a total of $9 + 180 = 189$ digits.  Each page numbered with a three-digit integer has three digits on it.   Since $9 + 90 \cdot 2 = 189 < 1260 < 9 + 90 \cdot 2 + 900 \cdot 3 = 2889$, the number of pages in the book must be a three-digit positive integer.  Since $1260 - 189 = 1071$, there must be $1071$ digits on pages numbered with three digits.

> Since $1071 = 3 \cdot 357$, the book must contain $357$ pages with three-digit numbers, the smallest of which is $100$. Thus, there are $356$ pages in the book numbered larger than $100$, so the book has $456$ pages.

Comment: Ok, Thank you !

Comment: +1, random trivia: Question 1 of the 1947 Stanford high school maths entrance comp (am not that old but got it from [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Stanford-Mathematics-Problem-Book-Solutions/dp/0486469247)!) had 1890 digits needed to number a 'bulky volume'. The choice of course results in a devilish 666 pages required, wonder if that raised a few eyebrows back then!

Answer (score 2):

(My first time posting an answer. I'm open for any critiques)

Note: We know the number of digits end in the range of a three-digit number because

pages $\;$ $1$ - $9 = 9$ $\;$ pages and digits ($1\,$- digit)

pages $\;$ $10$ - $99 = 90$ pages $*\;2 = 180$ digits (with $2\,$- digits)

pages $\;$ $100$ - $999 = 900$ pages $*\;3 = 2,700$ Digits (with $3\,$- digits)

The total number of digits from the question only goes up to 1260. Therefore, we know the answer ends in the $3$ - digits range.

$9 + 90\cdot 2 + (n-99)3 = 1260$

$  \;9 + 90 \cdot 2\; = 189$ (both one digits and double-digits)

$ \; (n-99)3 = 1260 - 189$

$=\;3n - 297 = 1071$

$3n = 1368$

$ n = 456$ pages

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format both, your questions and your answers :)

Comment: Noted, and thanks!

Comment: You have not explained why we know that the number of pages in the book is a three-digit number.  Doing so would justify your correct solution to the problem.

Comment: 1 - 9 = 9 digits in total 
10 - 99 x 2  = 189 digits in total
100 - 999 = 900 with three digits, and multiply 900 with 3 = 2,700 
Since the question refers to 1260 number of pages, we can already assume that the number of digits end in the three - digit number.

Comment: Sorry my answer above looks rather messy, I thought I indented them. But if this answers what you mean, I'll reedit my post. EDIT: Since the question refers to 1260 number of digits,

Comment: I think everything after "Note" in your answer, explains why you only have 3 digit pages, but also the formula you use to find 456. IMHO, your answer would be way more clear if it was at the begining. Anyway, welcome to MSE!

Comment: Also, I initially upvoted your answer, but I had to take it back because of the messy use of $=$ sign. You can't write things like "$3n−297=1071=3n=1368$", it burns the eyes of mathematicians. I'll suggest an edit to your answer, feel free to accept or reject it

Comment: Understood, and thanks for the critiques

Comment: You're welcome. To summarize all my critics about your initial answer, I would say that you should focus a bit more on explaining how to get the result, and less on what is the result. You'll find that quite a lot of accepted/best voted answers on this site are just hint on how to solve rather than full numerical solutions.